# Binding TextBlock to MouseEventHandlers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to bind a simple string to a TextBlock but it doesn't do anything.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(window_MouseMove);
    }

    public void window_MouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mouseXY = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

        string mouseXYstring = mouseXY.ToString();
    }
}
```

And XAML...:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MousePosition" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Text="{Binding Path=mouseXYstring}" />
```

Also tried...:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MousePosition" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Text="{Binding mouseXYstring}" />
```

And to do it from the window_MouseMove, removing the ´Text="{Binding mouseXYstring}´, but nothing seems to works:

```
    public void window_MouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mouseXY = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

        string mouseXYstring = mouseXY.ToString();

        TextBlock MP = new TextBlock();

        MP.Text = mouseXYstring;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i try it to a Textbox and its working this is my code

```
//mousemove inside my Textbox
    private void TextBox_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //txt is the name oh my textbox
        txt.Text = e.GetPosition(this).ToString();
    }

    //mousemove in my windows
    private void wn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //txt is the name oh my textbox
        txt.Text = e.GetPosition(this).ToString();
    }
```

but in your case you use a textblock and try this code

```
 public void window_MouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MousePosition.text = e.GetPosition(this).ToString();
}
```

Comment: This solved it, I was missing the "e." before the event, so I wasn't really calling the MouseEventArgs with my GetPosition.